# Problem using python pandas to extract a specific table data (div\tr\td) from a public website into CSV (with sample)

Tags: python, pandas

Purpose: I am practicing python pandas to get table data from a public website and exported into CSV file.
Public website URL: https://www.cde.org.cn/hymlj/listpage/c723ac5960cee1811b7be33a2acf8224
Problems: How to use python pandas to get the table data in above URL

Here is the code I wrote to test getting one or two pages data, but It couldn't return any data. Can anybody help figure it out what should be the correct code to get that table data? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.cde.org.cn/hymlj/listpage/c723ac5960cee1811b7be33a2acf8224"
def get_data(url):
    data = []
    for pageNum in range(1,3):
        try:
            data.append(pd.read_html(f'{url}&pageNum={pageNum}&pageSize=10&classId=c723ac5960cee1811b7be33a2acf8224&drugname=&pzwh=',header = 1, match='药品名称')[0].iloc[:-1,:-1])
            pd.concat(data).to_csv('test1.csv', index=False, encoding='utf_8_sig')
        except:
                if pageNum < (pageNum - 1):
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Has tried %d times to access url %s, all failed!", pageNum, url)
                    break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your solution. See comments for details.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# base url
url = "https://www.cde.org.cn/hymlj/listpage/c723ac5960cee1811b7be33a2acf8224"

# headers are needed to fake an actual browser access
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# start session to store cookies
s = requests.Session()

# open website once to obtain session cookies with faked user agent
s.get(url, headers=headers)

# this api url can be found using the browsers developer tools
api_url = "https://www.cde.org.cn/hymlj/getSmsList"

records = []

# there are a lot of pages, try higher numbers until there are no more results
for page in range(20):
    payload = {
        "pageNum": f"{page}",
        "pageSize": "1000",
        "classId": "c723ac5960cee1811b7be33a2acf8224",
        "drugname": "",
        "pzwh": ""
    }

    # perform post request to api url with headers and request payload
    res = s.post(api_url, payload, headers=headers)

    # add new records to list
    new_records = res.json()["data"]["records"]

    if len(new_records) == 0:
        # end loop if no more results are retrieved
        break

    # append new results to old ones
    records += new_records

# this is what you need
pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Comment: Hi Klops, thanks for your quick response! actually I'd like to practice how to download the table data using python pandas in that web. I tried using chrome developer console to get combined URL for each table data page, but failed to get data downloaded. Do you know how to use python pandas or chrome developer console to get data downloaded directly just like you did in firefox in an easier way directly? That will be great if you can tell the details or code so that I can try and run it to get data downloaded.. thanks!

Comment: I adjusted my answer, i could not figure out how to resend the request with different parameters (possible in firefox) but i posted a solution where you paste the command in the shell

Comment: Thanks Klops, I went through from step1 to step5 and stuck at step6, I got "getSmsList?..." and in step4, and selected "copy as cURL(bash)" in step5,
then I converted the result from "copy as cURL(bash)" to python, then what to do next? I want to perform it in python, but sorry I am not very clear here about how to proceed after step6 to get your mentioned 1000 rows in max into csv file.If not using python, how to export to csv file?

Comment: okay, i did some research and found a way for python only... i have never worked with sessions before, but this does the trick. if it helps, i'd be happy if you accept my first answer on stack overflow :-)

Comment: yep. I tried to run with your code and now can export the first 1000 row records to CSV.  I already mark it as 1st answer as the code is really helpful.. I also tried changing the range number to get all the data , but look like it can only get 1000 row data (the first 100 pages), any idea to get all of the other 398 pages?

Comment: there are two parameters, the results per request  `pageSize` and the requested page `pageNum`. When I tried it myself I found that the maximum page Size was 1000(?). So every page you receive should have 1000 rows. Since you iterate multiple pages (in my answer 20), you should get 20k rows with the version above?

Comment: I got 1k rows data (totally have 4998 rows for that table, 498 pages and 10 rows for each). I tested to change range number to 50 or even 500 and pageNum value keep 1000, it all return 1000 rows data for the 1st 100 pages in web table. BTW -  I had to remove these two rows code if len(new_records) == 0:  break , because it reported error due to saying break can only used with for loop, something like, I searched for internet, answer is break cannot work with if. Is it related with the data only get 1k rows?

Comment: i guess you executed lines of the code and then it happens that you execute code with a break statement but without the loop. in this case the error you observed is raised.

Comment: yep probably. but it should not impact the data return even I removed it. did you try the code in python and can you get 20k rows data ? I added few code to export data to excel, it can only get 1k rows by executing it in python.  pd.DataFrame(records).to_csv('test1.csv', index=False, encoding='utf_8_sig')

Comment: If  run the code as above, I retrieve 19974 records. However, there might be more if I increase `range(20)`, which I did not try.

Comment: Thanks Klops for your patience and plenty of time to help explain details! Are you running the code as above in python to retrieve 19974 records? and you didn't receive any error like the break statement without the loop if executing lines of code above? I am just trying to understand if I execute incorrectly and why I couldn't retrieve the same number of records (actually far less than this number)...

Comment: exactly, I copy the code to an empy file and execute it with python  3.6 or 3.7 (i can check later)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Klops, now I use Python 3.6 command window and run the code successfully without any error and get expected result. previously I used JupyterNotebook in Anaconda to run the code, that's why I got error and didn't get expected results......